# Войти на другом сайте через Steam. Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, auth, steam

Необходимо нажать кнопку войти на сайте с авторизацией через Steam. Не знаю, как это сделать.

[Buff163_Auth_Link](https://steamcommunity.com/openid/login?openid.mode=checkid_setup&openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0&openid.realm=https%3A%2F%2Fbuff.163.com%2F&openid.sreg.required=nickname%2Cemail%2Cfullname&openid.assoc_handle=None&openid.return_to=https%3A%2F%2Fbuff.163.com%2Faccount%2Flogin%2Fsteam%2Fverification%3Fback_url%3D%252Faccount%252Fsteam_bind%252Ffinish&openid.ns.sreg=http%3A%2F%2Fopenid.net%2Fextensions%2Fsreg%2F1.1&openid.identity=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&openid.claimed_id=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select)

Пробовал нажимать все //input элементы и submit() все //form элементы, не получилось.
Прошу помочь)

Comment: Добрый. Поправьте вопрос - добавьте свой код и трейс ошибки который кидает selenium.

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.find_element_by_id('imageLogin').click()
```

Просто по id